# Laravel Broadcast Event Private

Tags: laravel-5

I have been trying tog et private channels working with Laravel, and laravel-websockets

I got past a few hurdles, but the remaining one is on trying to auth:

```
preg_match(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (?&lt; at offset 13
```

That error seems to be related to:

```
 …/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/Broadcaster.php150
```

I guess the relavant pieces of code would be the echo config and listen.

bootstrap.js

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    encrypted: false,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
});
```

admin.blade.php

```
 Echo.private('messages.{{Auth::id()}}')
    .listen('NewMessageNotification', (e) => {
      console.log(e.message.message);
});
```

Just in case, channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('messages.{$toUserId}', function ($user, $toUserId) {
    // return true;
    return $user->id == $toUserId;
});
```

If I remove the private, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Broadcast::channel('messages.{$toUserId}', function ($user, $toUserId) {
// return true;
return $user->id == $toUserId;
```

});

The problem was the $ in the channel...

This is the correct way

```
Broadcast::channel('messages.{toUserId}', function ($user, $toUserId) {
    // return true;
    return $user->id == $toUserId;
});
```